# Can't see MySQL database from terminal that I created on Workbench using "SHOW DATABASES"

Tags: mysql, mysql-cli

I have recently downloaded MySQL community and MySQL workbench on my MacOs.
I created database on workbench and I am able to do updates and work there.

But when I try to do for ex: `"SHOW DATABASES` from terminal I am not able to see the databases I have created using workbench

All the commands are working and are fine here in MySQL workbench

[image]

But at the same time, I am unable to see any of my databases that i created using workbench

[image]

This is not mine, but I expect to get similar output.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `show databases;` rather than `show databases`.  MySQL uses `;` to indicate the end of a statement, so you need to add `;` after a statement. You lost the `;` while using terminal.